# How UDP checksum get IP address to make pseudo header in transport layer?

Tags: ipv4, tcp, layer3, udp, layer4

We know that `UDP` checksum's pseudo header contains the most important parts of the `IP header,` that is, `source and destination address, protocol number and data length.`

I hope that the concept of `IP addresses` is present in the `network layer` and the `transport layer` is above it, so how does the `transport layer` know the `IP  address` at the sending side because at the sender side, first the `transport layer` header is first encapsulated around the data coming from `application layer` and then the `IP header` is attached. I mean, how does the `transport layer` get to know the `IP address` when this facility is present at the bottom layer (`Network layer`) to make `pseudo header` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These layers are just abstract concepts. They don't actively do anything by their own. Instead such models are a tool to deal with complexity, get a common understanding of the functionality and to structure the code in a way which can also be understood and managed by others.

This means there is no *"transport layer know ..."*. There is instead a specific implementation (usually in the OS) dealing with all the different layers and which can also easily exchange information between these layers, like the IP address.

Comment: I have this related one more question, could I edit the question?

Comment: @AlokMaity: No. Questions should not be made a moving target. One can clarify the question or add more details while editing, but one should not add what was asked or add more questions to it. Please ask a new question instead with full context.