# Why the pseudo-header is not transmitted with the UDP datagram?

Tags: ipv4, tcp, udp, layer4

I have read from **E. Comer - Internetworking with TCP/IP 4th edition** that *"The purpose of using a pseudo-header is to verify that the UDP datagram has reached its correct destination. The key to understanding the pseudo-header lies in realizing that the correct destination consists of a specific machine and a specific protocol port within that machine. The UDP header itself specifies only the protocol port number. Thus, to verify the destination, UDP on the sending machine computes a checksum that covers the destination IP address as well as the UDP datagram. The pseudo-header is not transmitted with the UDP datagram, nor is it included in the length."*

But I asked one [question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76197/how-udp-checksum-get-ip-address-to-make-pseudo-header-in-transport-layer/76201?noredirect=1#comment136201_76201) from that understands the UDP datagram is transmitted with pseudo header. I don't understand the exact concepts.

Comment: a udp pseudoheader consists of udp header + IP addresses from IP header. Every UDP packet is transmitted inside an IP packet which has IP header. Thus all information in pseudoheader is transmitted. Just not all inside UDP header. And there is no point on having IP addresses in a packet twice.

Comment: @effenok when packets reaches in receiver side in transport layer the layer3 header will be omitted. So how could we calculate checksum with pseudo IP header in layer4?

Comment: you have to implement your protocol stack on end systems so that this is possible.

Comment: @effenok protocol stack available for every 7 layer?

Comment: usually, you have protocol stack up to layer 4 implemented by the operating system. the rest is part of application.

Comment: @effenok protocol stack means layer1 protocol + layer2 protocol...... Upto transport layer protocol?

Comment: hm ..., according to wikipedia "protocol stack" means the hardware/software that actually does protocol processing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_stack. I would say it starts at layer 1 and goes up to whatever is necessary.

Comment: @Till now I known that protocol stack is, the last header(Data link layer) that is added at sender side is the first header (Data link layer)  is removed from the receiver side and so on. How protocol stack contains the entry of layer 3 in layer4?

Comment: forget the word protocol stack. A host must implement its layer 3 and layer 4 in such a way that layer 4 checksum can be calculated and verified. How it does it, is up to the host.

Comment: Layer3 header is discarded in layer3 of receiver. So my question how layer4 get layer3 address?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129664/discussion-between-alok-maity-and-effenok).

Comment: this is "in theory there is no difference between theory and practice, but in practice there is" kind of situation. Let's say so: when layer 3 passes the packet (witout IP header) it can also pass IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "pseudo header" is a way to include vital information from the IP header in the UDP checksum. You could also call it "virtual header".

Basically, the UDP checksum is calculated on the UDP datagram *plus selected fields from the IP header*. The UDP handler is provided with sufficient information from the underlying network layer to calculate the checksum that way. Actually *sending* that pseudo header along with the UDP datagram would be completely redundant.

Comment: But Wikipedia saying pseudo header going to with udp header for checksum calculation.

Comment: Yes, it's used for checksum calculation. But no, it isn't transmitted along with the datagram (just the information is, elsewhere).

Comment: but during transmission what will contained by 16 bit checksum? Only checksum value?

Comment: The checksum is calculated over the payload and the pseudo header.

Comment: when packets reaches in receiver side in transport layer the layer3 header will be omitted. So how could we calculate checksum with pseudo IP header in layer4?

Comment: The IP stack passes all required information to UDP to recreate the pseudo header and recalculate the checksum.

Comment: You mean all necessary layer3 information passes to udp in layer4?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote (the information is passed over the inter-layer programming interface, not 'in layer 4').